# Path variable v/s Request Param variable with PUT method

Tags: json, spring

Can any one please advice when to use Path variable and when to use Request Param variable with Rest API using PUT method .

Comment: A path variable could be used for ids, e.g. in GET /students/123, a request param could be used for searching within objects, e.g. /students/query?name="Ben".

Comment: thanks . my question is related to PUT request . Is it good practice to use Path variable with PUT request ?